# Always Query Using Current User in Parse iOS

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfuser

As I understand it, I can auto-populate the `ACL` column in any newly-added records in Parse by setting this:

```
PFACL.setDefaultACL(PFACL(), withAccessForCurrentUser: true)
```

Is there a way to always perform queries using `PFUser.currentUser()` as a filter by default? Or do I have to specify the user with every query?

```
query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no such features in `Parse` SDK. But you can always use swift features like extensions to add required functional:

```
extension PFQuery {
    class func userQueryForClassName(className: String) -> PFQuery {
        let query = PFQuery(className: className)
        query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
        return query;
    }
}

let query = PFQuery.userQueryForClassName("test")
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I don't need to specify the `currentUser()` or the `ACL` at all. It happens automatically as long as a `PFUser` is logged in.

See here for reference: https://parse.com/questions/query-for-tableview-specifying-an-acl